# Why doesn't custom hook return updated data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

There is a custom useMarkers hook for converting markers into clusters on the map.
It takes needed props,but the essential one are options prop.

```
const { markersArray, supercluster } = useMarkers({
    points: transformedMarkers,
    bounds,
    zoom,
    options: defaultOptions2, // <=== HERE IS WHAT WE NEED
});
```

And here is it from the inside:

```
const initialMarkersData = {
    markersArray: [],
    supercluster: []
};

const useMarkers = (initialData = {}) => {
    const [markersData, setMarkersData] = useState(initialMarkersData);

    const { clusters, supercluster } = useSupercluster(initialData);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (initialData.zoom <= 17) {
            // console.log("SET NON-CLUSTERS");
            setMarkersData({
                ...markersData,
                markersArray: initialData.points,
            });
        } else {
            // console.log("SET CLUSTERS");
            setMarkersData({
                markersArray: clusters,
                supercluster,
            });
        }
    }, [initialData.zoom, clusters, supercluster]);

    return markersData;
};
```

Inside useMarkers I`m passing props to another hook, useSupercluster (comes from separate npm library), and depending on **options** prop it should return an updated clusters array, and depending on the zoom level an additional useEffect should change the markersData, which is then returns as a result.

And the problem is that when I add a condition for passing different **options**, the new array is not returned.

For example, if I pass **options** like this, it works:

```
options: defaultOptions2,
```

But if I add condition instead of just single *defaultOptions2*

```
options: zoom < 17 ? defaultOptions : defaultOptions2
```

It doesn't work. If I console.log initialData inside useMarkers hook, I will see new **options**, so the condition works correct, but although this hook is re-renders, it looks like useSupercluster() doesn`t reinitialize again because it doesn't return modified array according to new **options**. What could be the reason?

UPDATE*: I tried to investigate this behavior with debugger and everything looks correct. The supercluster property, which is destructured from useSupercluster hook, has to have the this **options** in it, and although  new options successfully passed to useSupercluster within initialData, **supercluster** property got the empty object at the end;

Comment: Hey Yehor. Did you try with the help of a debugger why is it not returning what you expect?

Comment: Hey, Neon, I`ve updated the issue. In short - everything looks fine, options prop successfully passed into useSupercluster hook within Initial data, but looks like the main problem is somewhere inside this useSupercluster hook, since at the and supercluster property (destructured from useSuperCluster) ends up with empty options field (must be equal to what we are passing) , so looks like its not updating;